# Error in UseMethod("select_") : no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "character"

Tags: r, dplyr, error-handling, tidyverse

I am trying to extract some columns from the data which is result of analysis. The data is composed of 592 rows and 20 variables.

When I run the code as below, I got the **error** message

> "Error in UseMethod("select_") : no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "character" "

```
unused_cols <- -c(2:9)

pvals_long <- pvals %>%
  map(function(x){
    x <- x %>%
      dplyr::select(unused_cols) %>%
      gather(key = "celltype_pair", value = "pvalue", -interacting_pair)
    x
  })
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please can you include some data (use `dput(pvals)`) so that your problem can be reproduced.

Answer (score 2):

1. `map` is not needed. Mapping on a dataframe means that you are trying to apply your function on each column. However, `select` expects a dataframe, while in your code it gets a vector. That's what the error is telling you.
2. `unused_cols <- -c(2:9)` will not work. Put the `-`in the call to `select`.

Try this:

```
unused_cols <- c(2:9)

pvals_long <- pvals %>%
    select(-unused_cols) %>%
    gather(key = "celltype_pair", value = "pvalue", -interacting_pair)
```

Comment: Thanks! I have run revised code, but I got another error: Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘select’ for signature ‘"spec_tbl_df"’

Comment: Sounds like a name conflict. See e.g. https://heima.hafro.is/~einarhj/spatialr/bit_conflicts.html. Try dplyr::select instead of just select to make sure you call select from dplyr. PS: my fault. (;